# With Docker on Windows, workbench for SPFx no longer works

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I think it started with @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1:
With Docker on Windows, we used to apply [this workaround in SPWebBuildRig.js](https://github.com/waldekmastykarz/docker-spfx#cant-access-workbench-and-bundles-in-sharepoint-framework-160-on-windows) to load the resources correctly in the local workbench.
But SPWebBuildRig.js changed significantly and I couldn't find how to apply the workaround anymore.

Now, to get back to a working state, I need to find a way to set `internalModuleBaseUrls` in manifests.js to "https://localhost:4321/dist/" (instead of "https://0.0.0.0:4321/dist/").
I did a few (unsuccessful) tests:
In node_modules/@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench/local-workbench/manifests.js, I tried to replace this:

```javascript
manifest.loaderConfig.internalModuleBaseUrls = [manifestsFileUrl];
```

by this:

```javascript
manifest.loaderConfig.internalModuleBaseUrls = ["https://localhost:4321/dist/"];
```

But sadly it has no effect.
I just found that this issue has been reported in https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7076 (no solution so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated the issue you referenced. If you happen to still be using the local workbench with SPFx 1.12.1, you can resolve this by updating line 376 of node_modules/@microsoft/spfx-heft-plugins/lib/plugins/webpackConfigurationPlugin/WebpackConfigurationGenerator.js to the following:

```
const debugBaseUrl = `${serveConfig.https ? 'https' : 'http'}://localhost:${serveConfig.port || 4321}/dist/`;
```

Comment: Worth noting the file location is still correct, but in the latest version of this plugin it's line 393, you can find the proper line by searching on "debugBaseUrl"